# Subset condition within category in R

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

I'm using a survey dataset (ESS) that includes several countries per wave, and several individuals within each wave. It looks something like this:

| Country | Wave |
| --- | --- |
| AT | 1 |
| AT | 1 |
| AT | 1 |
| AT | 2 |
| AT | 3 |
| AT | 3 |
| AT | 4 |
| AT | 4 |
| AT | 5 |
| AT | 6 |
| AT | 7 |
| AT | 8 |
| AT | 9 |
| AT | 9 |
| BE | 1 |
| BE | 2 |
| BE | 2 |
| BE | 3 |
| BE | 4 |
| BE | 5 |
| BE | 6 |
| BE | 7 |
| BE | 7 |
| BE | 9 |
| BE | 9 |

I would like to filter/subset the data to get a new clean dataframe that includes **only** countries that are included in **all** of the waves, which range from 1 to 9. In other words, I would need to select countries based on the condition that they have observations in all 9 waves. In the example above, only "AT" would be selected as "BE" is missing wave #8.

This sounds rather straightforward but I am struggling to find a simple way to go about it (likely due to the fact that I am new in R).

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select `Country` which has `all` the values from 1 to 9 in `Wave`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% group_by(Country) %>% filter(all(1:9 %in% Wave)) %>% ungroup
df1

#   Country  Wave
#   <chr>   <int>
# 1 AT          1
# 2 AT          1
# 3 AT          1
# 4 AT          2
# 5 AT          3
# 6 AT          3
# 7 AT          4
# 8 AT          4
# 9 AT          5
#10 AT          6
#11 AT          7
#12 AT          8
#13 AT          9
#14 AT          9
```

This can also be written in base R and `data.table` -

```
#Base R
df1 <- subset(df, as.logical(ave(Wave, Country, 
              FUN = function(x) all(1:9 %in% x))))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(1:9 %in% Wave)], Country]
```

Answer (score 0):

In r, there is often several ways to solve the same problem. Here is a slight variation

```
library(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
     Country = c("AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT",
                 "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE",
                 "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE"),
        Wave = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
                 7, 7, 9, 9)
)

df_new<-df %>%
  mutate(Country=Country %>% as.factor(),Wave=Wave %>% as.factor()) %>%
  group_by(Country,Wave, .drop=FALSE) %>%
  summarize(n=n(), ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarize(all_waves=if_else(min(n)>0, TRUE, FALSE))
```

First wer group by country and wave and summarize total number in each group. Then we group by country and summarize the groups where the minimum number is greater than 0.

Comment: Thank you, also useful to understand this variation.